# Problems with installing Ubuntu on an HP Laptop

Tags: system-installation, hp

Dear Ubuntu Community,

I was wondering how one would install Ubuntu 13.10 on an HP pavillion g6 laptop. I tried from a live CD but had no luck. So Mageia worked after trying SUSE, Mint and Ubuntu. Does anyone have any ideas how I could install Ubuntu? And if it could be done, would I have problems with drivers for things or software repositories?

Comment: Are you not able to boot ubuntu after installing? or not even able to install it? What happens when you try to install? Tell what error you are getting?

Comment: Does it use a UEFI boot partition? That may be part of the problem. This page *may* help. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is End-of-Life.  Is it important to you that it is 13.10 or would you be willing to change to 12.04 or 14.04?

Comment: @0xSheepdog Honestly I'm a bit of a noob - UEFI? Basically Ubuntu didn't boot so I installed Mageia as Ubuntu,SUSE and Mint didn't work.

Comment: 1) Please advise the model number. 2) You should be able to install but may need to add drivers for better video performance - ran into that on my HP laptop. 3) Repositories will not be a problem. 4) Since the current Mageia doesn't support UEFI Boot, UEFI ain't the issue. 5) Ideally, try getting 14.04, install it, & write down the error messages it throws at you when it tries to install. Without error messages, we're guessing as to the cause of the problem. 6) To add the error messages, click on the grey `edit` link above the first comment and add the error messages to your original post.

Comment: @K7AAY Laptop model= HP Pavillion g6 1381ea. I will try 14.04 asap. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: UEFI and EFI = replacement for BIOS on many (most?) newer PCs and MACs, details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface

Comment: Yes, it has UEFI instead of the friendly BIOS.

Comment: Problem solved, installed Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you for all help!